# Log rotation of stdout?

Tags: linux, shell-script, redirection, stdout, logrotate

I have a Linux program which can write information to stdout and stderr.

I have a shell script which redirects that output to a file in `/var/log`.  (Via `>>` and `2>&1`.)

Is there a way to make that log file rotate?  (max size, then switch to a different file, keep only a limited number of files)

I've seen a few answers which talk about the `logrotate` program, which sounds good, but they also seem to be focused on programs which are generating log files internally and handle HUP signals.  Is there a way to make this work with a basic output redirection script?

Comment: Why can't you just modify the script that redirects the output to contain the logic for the rotation?

Comment: I could, if someone could tell me how to detect the size of a logfile and rotate it out from under the stdout of a process without disturbing that process.  I don't *have* to use `logrotate` if there's a better option, that just sounded like a convenient starting point for discussion.

Comment: You don't have to use logrotate, but using logrotate just saves time... There is usually little point reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Exactly my point.  So is there a way to make logrotate work with an ongoing process's redirected stdout?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As an alternative, you could pipe the output through tools designed with the primary purpose of maintaining size-capped, automatically rotated, log file sets, such as:

- Dan Bernstein's [`multilog`](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/multilog.html) from daemontools
- Bruce Guenter's [`multilog`](http://untroubled.org/daemontools-encore/multilog.8.html) from daemontools-encore
- Laurent Bercot's [`s6-log`](http://skarnet.org/software/s6/s6-log.html) from s6
- Gerrit Pape's [`svlogd`](http://smarden.org/runit/svlogd.8.html) from runit
- Wayne Marshall's [`tinylog`](http://b0llix.net/perp/site.cgi?page=tinylog.8) from perp
- My [`cyclog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/cyclog.html) from [nosh](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/)

Tools to then process `multilog`-format log file sets include, amongst others:

- Russ Allbery's [`multilog-watch`](http://www.eyrie.org./%7Eeagle/software/multilog-watch/docs.html)
- [`logrange`](http://code.dogmap.org/djbdns/#logrange)
- Paul Kremer's [`multilog-stamptail`](http://pol.spurious.biz/projects/scripting/multilog-stamptail.pod.html)
- My [`follow-log-directories`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/follow-log-directories.html) from nosh
- My [`export-to-rsyslog`](http://jdebp.eu./Softwares/nosh/guide/export-to-rsyslog.html) from nosh

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2015). "[Logging](http://jdebp.info/FGA/daemontools-family.html#Logging)". *The daemontools family*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2016). *[Don't use `logrotate` or `newsyslog` in this century.](http://jdebp.info/FGA/do-not-use-logrotate.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/326166/5132

Comment: Thanks, `multilog` looks like just what I needed.

Comment: multilog seems to be the only plug-and-play solution in debian (daemontools has an official package). But in my particular case, where I wanted to store the logs on a fat32 partition, the rotating does not work, since multilog wants to use a symlink. No plug and play for me:)

Comment: That cannot be true, as `multilog` nowhere creates or demands symbolic links.  It is entirely neutral with respect to them.

Comment: URL of "Don't use logrotate or newsyslog in this century" has extra dot

Answer (score 19):

the `rotatelogs` tool shipped with apache (in the `bin` dir)  (see [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html)) takes input from stdin and rotates the log after some specific amount of time

Comment: I tried `rotatelogs` with truncation and file size limit (`| rotatelogs -t $LOGFILE 10M`) , but it does not append to the existing log file but overwrites it each time. Any idea what's missing?

Answer (score 15):

I had similar problem and had initially discard logrotate but it turned out logrotate can actually do this well, the key directive is "**copytruncate**". For some reason that term didn't come up on any of the googling I did, so I am adding this answer to clarify exactly how to use it for this case.

The trick is this *only works* if the redirect is done with "**>>**" (append) instead of "**>**" (create).

Config File (truncate.cfg):

```
/tmp/temp.log {
    size 10M
    copytruncate
    rotate 4
    maxage 100
}
```

Test Program (never gives up file). You can watch it filling disk and though deleting logfile will appear to work it will not actually free up any space on the disk:

```
cat /dev/urandom >> /tmp/temp.log
```

Running log rotate:

```
logrotate truncate.cfg
```

Comment: It's a nice theory, but it doesn't actually work on any system I've tried it on.  The file does not actually get truncated and the program continues to append to it as before.  (And yes, that's even with the redirection done via >>.)  ((BTW, this answer was already given previously.))

Comment: … as discussed in [logrotate won’t truncate original file](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117852/80216) (on our Unix&Linux site). Also, `echo /dev/urandom >> /tmp/temp.log` will write 13 deterministic characters to `/tmp/temp.log` and then immediately exit. Did you mean `cat /dev/urandom`?

Comment: Just tested here, and it seems to work. Content of file is copied to new log file. Original file is kept open by process and is truncated (size now shows 0).

Comment: Be careful about the possible data loss with copytruncate.

Comment: +1 although "Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so some logging data might be lost."

Answer (score 14):

If you can have it go to one of the standard log streams (syslog, daemon, cron, user, security, mail, etc.) you can use the [`logger`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) command and pipe to it instead.

```
echo "Hello." | logger -p daemon.info
```

Otherwise, you may be better off piping your logged content to a custom program or script to handle it, or look at setting up the [`logrotate`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) configuration.

EDIT: JdeBP's answer seems to have what you may be looking for.

Comment: +1 for simplicity. BTW, you can also configure a custom facility (local0) instead of the standard ones (daemon in your example)

Answer (score 5):

I like `multilog` for my use case, but my use case is so trivial/simple that it is not laid out very simply in the docs/examples I found.  Here is a simple multilog rotate example:

```
mkdir /tmp/myapp
./myapp | multilog t s10000 n5 '!tai64nlocal' /tmp/myapp 2>&1
```

Some notes:

- this dumps logs into that /tmp/myapp/ directory
- the s10000 represents 10,000 bytes*
- the n5 represents 5 files.*  The 'current' log counts as one of the files, so this includes 4 older logs + 'current'
- this is based on, adapted from the examples provided by François Beausoleil at: http://blog.teksol.info/pages/daemontools/best-practices
- I don't understand many of the options - I refer you to the various documentation to extend this...
- The docs warn that: `"Note that running processor may block any program feeding input to multilog."` where 'processor' is the `'!tai64nlocal'` portion of the command

*For many applications, these are poor choices for long term use.  They do allow you to observe the behavior of filling and rotating the logs more quickly than large logs do.

Finally, don't forget to nohup if required!  With nohup, you do not need the `2>&1` (s=10e6 and n=30 here):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/myapp
nohup ./myapp | multilog t s10000000 n30 '!tai64nlocal' /tmp/myapp &
```

That command should get you started.

Comment: Very useful example! Thanks for posting it!

Answer (score 3):

> So is there a way to make logrotate work with an ongoing process's redirected stdout?

Yes! Check out the "copytruncate" directive offered by logrotate. Specifying that instructs logrotate to handle this very situation: a simple program that keeps its log file open indefinitely.

One caveat may or may not be a problem in your situation:

> Note that there is a very small time slice between copying the file and truncating it, so  some  logging  data  might be lost.

Anecdotally, I've seen some "real world" log sources that do encourage users to apply this directive. There's some discussion of this option [here](https://serverfault.com/a/292521/123535).

Answer (score 3):

Use split, it's part of coreutils. It can take stdin and split it into chunks (based on chunk size, or number of lines, etc.).

Example:

```
app | split --bytes 1G - /var/logs/put-prefix-here
```

Note dash (-) instructs "split" to use stdin instead of file.

Comment: Can you expand your answer to describe how to do that?  Thanks.

Comment: just updated my reply with example.

Comment: The 1G is an arbitrary size, after which it starts a new file?

Comment: This isn't a particualrly good solution to the problem because it means you can end up with half a message in one file and half in the next. There's also the risk of data loss if the machine crashes while `split` has data in what could be a large buffer. Given that there are multiple tools that solve this problem properly, I don't think this kind of roll-your-own solution can be at all recommended.

Comment: All tools have their use.. I don't think anything that works with pipes will "guarantee" no data loss. This is quick and dirty solution that would work just fine for lots of jobs. Also "split" has option to split by number of lines (instead of number of bytes). It's a good-old unix tool which I think still has it's uses.

Comment: @David Richerby- how about adding -u for unbuffered?

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add to Sam Hendley's comment above:

**The trick is this only works if the redirect is done with `>>` (append) instead of `>` (create).**

I ran into the same problem where the original file just keeps growing if you use `>` (create) but if you use `>>` (append) Logrotate copytruncate works beautifully and as expected. The original file goes back down to zero bytes and the program continues writing.

Redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a rotating logfile:

1. `some-program.sh >> /tmp/output.txt 2>&1 &`
2. Create a logrotate config file under `/etc/logrotate.d` called whatever, output_roll in my case.

   Sample config for my case:

   ```
   /tmp/output.txt {
       notifempty
       missingok
       size 1G
       copytruncate
       start 0
       rotate 15
       compress
   }
   ```
3. Setup your cron job inside the `/etc/crontab` file

   ```
   *  *  *  *  * root /usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/output_roll
   ```

   This will check the file every minute. You can adjust to suit your needs.
4. Start it up:

   ```
   $> service crond restart
   ```
5. That's it

**Note: I also had a problem with SELinux being set to `SELINUX=enforcing` so I set it to `SELINUX=disabled`.**

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [logrotee](https://github.com/singalen/logrotee) this weekend. I probably wouldn't if I've read @JdeBP's great answer and `multilog`.

I focused on it being lightweight and being able to bzip2 its output chunks like:

```
verbosecommand | logrotee \
  --compress "bzip2 {}" --compress-suffix .bz2 \
  /var/log/verbosecommand.log
```

There's a lot of to be done and tested yet, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can use such a simple bash scripts:
./my_app|./log_rotate.sh log.txt 5 mylogdir 10 1000

log named as log.txt ,rotate 5 times,stored in mylogdir, rotate 10 times,log rotate on 1000 lines, dir rotate on each start up of my_app

log_rotate.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
logname=$1
lognumber=$2
dirname=$3
dirnumber=$4
line=$5
date
mkdir -p ${dirname}
cd ${dirname}
rm "data${dirnumber}" -rfv
for i in $(seq $((dirnumber - 1)) -1 0)
do
        mv "data$i" "data$(($i+1))" 2>/dev/null && echo mv "data$i" "data$(($i+1))"
done
mkdir -p data0
cd data0
dd of="${logname}" bs=2048 count=${line} 2>/dev/null
date
mv "${logname}" "${logname}.first" 2>/dev/null && echo mv "${logname}" "${logname}.first"
while true
do
        for i in $(seq $((lognumber - 1)) -1 1)
        do
                mv "${logname}.$i" "${logname}.$(($i+1))" 2>/dev/null && echo mv "${logname}.$i" "${logname}.$(($i+1))"
        done
        mv "${logname}" "${logname}.1" 2>/dev/null && echo mv "${logname}" "${logname}.1"
        dd of="${logname}" bs=2048 count=${line} 2>/dev/null
        date
done
```

Answer (score 0):

As we were not fully satisfied with listed tools here, we wrote another one (sorry!) called `log_proxy`.

Main features:

- usable as a pipe (`myapp myapp_arg1 myapp_arg2 |log_proxy /log/myapp.log`)
- configurable log rotation suffix with `stftime` placeholders (for example: `.%Y%m%d%H%M%S`)
- can limit the number of rotated files (and delete oldest)
- can rotate files depending on their size (in bytes)
- can rotate files depending on their age (in seconds)
- does not need a specific log directory for a given app (you can have one directory with plenty of different log files from different apps)
- several instances of the same app can log to the same file without issue (example: `myapp arg1 |log_proxy --use-locks /log/myapp.log` and `myapp arg2 |log_proxy --use-locks /log/myapp.log` can run at the same time)
- implemented in C (fast and do not eat a lot of memory)
- configurable with CLI options as well with env variables
- usable as a wrapper to capture stdout and stderr (`log_proxy_wrapper --stdout=/log/myapp.stdout --stderr=/log/myapp.stderr -- myapp myapp_arg1 myapp_arg2`)
- binary releases with no dependency, even on a very old distribution like `CentOS 6` (2011!)

Comments, issues and PRs welcome on:
https://github.com/metwork-framework/log_proxy