# Log rotation with compression?

Tags: linux, compression, logging

I'm running a process on Linux (CentOS 7) which produces a lot of output on stdout. Sending it all to a file will result in a file size greater than 1 TB. But happily the output is quite compressible - it consists of lots of quite repetitive text.

My thought is, can I use some kind of log rotation program like those described here: ( [Log rotation of stdout?](https://superuser.com/questions/291368/log-rotation-of-stdout) ), but where once a log is no longer current, it is compressed (and never deleted)? So I end up writing, say, a couple of GB to the file, compress it, and keep writing to a fresh file?

Comment: What is version of you Linux since Linux is just a kernel, what is name of your distributive? Many of them already has what you need

Comment: @Alex it's CentOS 7

Comment: You mean like with logrotate?

Comment: I have investigated an issue you may encounter. Please see [*Is redirection with `>>` equivalent to `>` when target file doesn't yet exist?*](https://superuser.com/q/1342489/432690)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [logrotate](https://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) for this. CentOS 7 is using [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd) so you can configure a [scheduled logrotate task](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers) with something like this:

- Create a logrotate config file in `/etc/systemd/system` called `mylogrotate.config` with the following content:

  ```
  /path/to/your/logfile/*.log {
      compress
      copytruncate
      delaycompress
      minsize 1G
      missingok
      nomail
      notifempty
      rotate 30
  }
  ```

This will tell logrotate to do the following:

- Old versions of log files are compressed with gzip by default.
- Truncate the original log file in place after creating a copy, instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new one.
- Postpone compression of the previous log file to the next rotation cycle so you're going to have two uncompressed log files.
- Log files are rotated when they grow bigger than 1Gbytes.
- If the log file is missing, go on to the next one without issuing an error message.
- Don't mail old log files to any address.
- Log files are rotated 30 times before being removed so you'll have 30 old log files. Anything older than that will be deleted.

Create a systemd service. Create a file in `/etc/systemd/system` called `mylogrotate.service` with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rotate My Log

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/systemd/system/mylogrotate.config --state /etc/systemd/system/mylogrotate.state --verbose
```

Let's schedule this task. Create a third file in `/etc/systemd/system` called `mylogrotate.timer` with the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=Rotate My Log Timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

This will run logrotate every hour.

All has been set up. Now enable the scheduled task.

```
systemctl enable mylogrotate.timer
systemctl start mylogrotate.timer
```

Of course do all this as root.

(I'm on Ubuntu but I hope this will work on CentOS without any issues)

Comment: `copytruncate` seems useful, but I think it will work if the redirection to the log file is done with `>>`; only then truncating the file causes the new content to appear from the beginning. Redirection with `>` keeps its (growing) offset, so any new data after the file is truncated causes the file to grow (with leading zeros) to the old size.